# Multiple NetworkCallback events (onAvailable) affecting app performance

Tags: android, performance, android-wifi, android-connectivitymanager

I need to display an alert screen when the device is losing network connectivity. When connectivity is back, I hide this alert. I'm using ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() to determine connectivity status. The app is being run on API 22 devices.

```
public void registerNetworkAvailability(final Context context, BroadcastReceiver networkAvailabilityReceiver) {
        context.registerReceiver(networkAvailabilityReceiver, new IntentFilter(NETWORK_AVAILABILITY_ACTION));
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(true));
            }

            @Override
            public void onLost(Network network) {
                if (!isAvailable(context))
                    context.sendBroadcast(getNetworkAvailabilityIntent(false));
            }
        };
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), networkCallback);
    }
```

It's registered in onCreate() method of my Activity

```
    networkAvailability = NetworkAvailability.getInstance();
    networkAvailability.registerNetworkAvailability(this, receiver);
```

And here is BroadcastReceiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) return;
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if (noConnectivity) {
            connectivityError = true;
            showNetworkAlert();
        } else {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = networkAvailability.getActiveNetworkInfo(getApplicationContext());
            if (networkInfo != null) {
                networkType = networkInfo.getType();
                Logger.i(TAG, "connection type: " + networkInfo.getTypeName());
                Logger.i(TAG, "connection IP: " + networkAvailability.getLocalIpAddress());
            }
            if (connectivityError) {
                connectivityError = false;
                showDialog(null);
                initConfiguration();
            }
        }
        if (updateDialog != null) {
            updateDialog.dismiss(null);
            updateDialog = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Usually, `onAvailable()` is being called 1-2 times after Wi-Fi is connected. But for some places where the app is running, there are multiple `onAvailable()` callbacks arriving every minute.

```
07-07 14:13:12.074  7343  7343 connection type: WIFI
07-07 14:13:12.077  7343  7343 connection IP: 192.168.1.216
07-07 14:13:24.160  7343  7343 connection type: WIFI
07-07 14:13:24.164  7343  7343 connection IP: 192.168.1.216
07-07 14:13:33.268  7343  7343 connection type: WIFI
07-07 14:13:33.278  7343  7343 connection IP: 192.168.1.216
07-07 14:13:45.409  7343  7343 connection type: WIFI
07-07 14:13:45.418  7343  7343 connection IP: 192.168.1.216
07-07 14:13:54.500  7343  7343 connection type: WIFI
07-07 14:13:54.512  7343  7343 connection IP: 192.168.1.216
```

This is affecting app performance, making the UI slow and unresponsive.

What may be the reason for that? How to improve performance in this case?

Comment: Are you unregistering your `networkCallback` via `connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)` in your `onDestroy`?

Comment: @Fabio yes i do

Comment: i get the same question.who can  help me